# Is it possible to use "dont" for places?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

For example, if I have the following sentences.

> J'aime Paris. J'arrive de Paris.

What would be the correct phrase with a relative pronoun?

> J'aime Paris, dont j'arrive.
>   J'aime Paris, d'où j'arrive.

Comment: *La ville dont je vient*, oui ; si on ne pense pas à utiliser *d'où*, c'est correct.

Comment: Donc, on peut utiliser les deux pronoms?

Comment: In some cases at least, yes. If I knew more, I'd post an answer :p

Comment: This is a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To answer shortly, both forms are correct although *d'où je viens* is more common and modern.**

---

This use of *dont* is [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont) (TLFi) marked as old-fashioned and/or literary, but I admit I'm quite surprised because I would have had assumed it more common.

Extract of the above linked article :

> II.− [Dépendant directement du verbe subordonné (actif, passif, pronominal) avec lequel il forme un syntagme verbal]
>   A.− [Rapports de sens entre *dont* et le verbe]
>   1. *Archaïque* et *littéraire*. [*Dont* marque la provenance, l'éloignement, l'extraction] Synononyme de *où*.
>   a) Au sens physique. [*Dont* marque le point de départ d'un mouvement]
>
> - *Le perdreau, (…) traînant encore **l'œuf dont il vient de sortir**.* (Cabanis, Rapp. phys. mor., t. 2, 1808, p. 321)
> - ***Des trottoirs dont il fallait descendre** chaque fois qu'on croisait un passant*. (Simenon, Vac. Maigret,1948, p. 7)
> - […] *le Carrefour, **propriété de famille aux environs de Pont-l'Évêque, dont il ne bougeait plus**, où il se ferait plaisir de me recevoir et de mettre à ma disposition ses papiers, sa bibliothèque et son érudition…* (Gide, Isabelle,1911, p. 603)
>
> Rem. 1. *Dont* ne peut avoir pour antécédent un adverbe de lieu.

And then again, there's this note just after the extract :

> Cet emploi archaïsant que les grammairiens condamnent est assez répandu chez les auteurs modernes avec les verbes qui demandent la préposition **de** (cf. Grevisse, § 562).

---

And [nGram confirms](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dont%20je%20viens&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) that *dont je viens* is less and less found in books. Searching for *d'où je viens* doesn't seem to give relevant results but it's obviously a search issue, probably because of accented characters.

edit : we should maybe forget this nGram I made, it's not very clear and moreover there's many other forms ruining the search results (falsely-positive example *le sujet dont je viens de parler*)

Comment: Re: the Grevisse reference, in my modern 14th edition, this is covered under §723 (§562 is the basic adjective agreement rule). Grevisse basically states there that the distinction in question is artificial and was never much followed.

Answer (score 4):

Il est difficile pour moi d'expliquer la règle, mais dans ce cas-ci, le plus communément utilisé est la seconde solution « *J'aime Paris, d'où j'arrive* ». La seconde est plus « empruntée ».

---

It's difficult for me to explain the rule, but in this case, the most in use is to say “*J'adore paris, d'où j'arrive*” (or “*J'arrive de Paris, que j'adore*”, but it changes the sentence a little). 
Sorry for not providing more explications, I hope this helps.

After some more research I can tell this:
You can use *dont* with a place when there's (a kind of) possession
“*le pays dont je suis issue*”.

I use this, but it's in French : http://www.synapse-fr.com/expression/dont.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
In french only, sorry.
```

Je pense que c'est le terme *j'arrive* qui est trompeur. Avec lui on peut employer dont et d'où, et ça gène la distinction. Pour mieux mettre en valeur la différence entre dont et d'où, il vaut mieux changer le *j'arrive* :

- J'aime Paris, dont l'étude historique se poursuit.
- J'aime Paris, dont certains quartiers sont agréables.

Dont veux dire duquel (ou assimilé), même lorsque je dis *J'aime Paris dont j'arrive* : Ici, ça ne veut pas dire d'où.

Il vaut mieux employer **d'où**, non seulement parce que c'est plus courant, mais parce que le terme correspond mieux à ce que l'on veut dire : duquel est juste une sorte de relance du terme Paris ; c'est juste parce qu'on sait que Paris est une ville que le sens se comprend dans votre exemple : si je dis *J'aime les fleurs dont j'arrive* (français incorrect), on voit que ça ne va pas.

Et tout cela, sous tout réserve que quelqu'un dise autre chose.

Comment: Je n'ai pas compri l'example "J'aime les fleurs dont j'arrive". 'arriver de quelque chose' est une expression en français?

Comment: C'est un exemple qui n'est pas du français correct. Donc, non, "arriver de quelque chose", n'est pas une expression française. Je modifie le texte pour que ce soit plus clair.

Comment: +1 pour mettre en exergue la notion de *mouvement dans le présent*. `Paris dont je suis originaire` [j'y suis peut être né] (1) `, et aussi d'où je viens` [j'y étais dans une autre époque, mais je n'y suis plus] (2) :: (1) il s'agit : de se définir par rapport à un lieu, (2) de se positionner par rapport à ce même lieu dans "l'ici et maintenant".